# Subgroup isomorphism problem

Tags: gr.group-theory

I was searching for the graph isomorphism problem because I was looking for NP-COMPLETE problems to write about in a article I`m writing.

Learning about the problem a thing came to my mind, does this holds for groups to?

If I give a group A and a goup B and ask if there is a subgroup of B isomorphic to A, is this decision problem NP-COMPLETE?

If so, how do I prove it?

If not, why?

Comment: Can you give me a reference to understand this?

Comment: I have some knowledge in logic and model theory, if it's related.

Comment: Hmm, unfortunately the argument I had in mind didn't work. Many undecidability results about finitely presented groups follow from the Adian-Rabin theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adian%E2%80%93Rabin_theorem) but the hypotheses of that theorem don't actually apply here.

Comment: The triviality problem is undecidable for finitely presented torsion-free groups, so you can take $A=\mathbb{Z}$. This is a well known extension of the Adyan—Rabin theorem.

Comment: The question as stated makes sense for finite groups, though.

Comment: This discussion really gone to a path I didn't expected, problaby I gonna study it a bit harder.

Comment: There are a bunch of problems in finite group theory, including centralizers of elements in subgroups of $S_n$,  that are regarded as candidates for being strictly between P and NP. Normalizers in $S_n$ of subgroups might be NP-complete, but nothing has been proved. (Of course the problems have to be phrased as decision problems, like is the specified subgroup of $C_G(g)$ the whole of $C_G(g)$ for given $G \le S_n$.)

Comment: Is there a field of complexity theory that lies in algeba?

Comment: I konw about geometric complexity that studies louwer bounds for some algebraic problems, but I've never saw an book nor paper on complexity theory and pure algebra.

Comment: There is a lot of literature on complexity problems in finite group theory. Just do a search for complexity in group theory. Leading authors are Babai and Eugene Luks. In fact the proofs of Babai's recent ground-breaking work on the graph isomorphism theorem involve techniques for computing in subgroups of $S_n$.

Comment: I'd suggest you edit the question to clarify what you are looking for (the comments are not the right place to amend a question). In particular it would be useful to be specific about the input (a group is not an input, but rather a finite presentation).

Comment: On that theme, for finite groups there are a number of different options for input. In practice, generators of the group (as permutations or matrices) tend to be the preferred option, but for some problems, including group isomorphism, even with input via group multiplication table, it is unknown whether there are polynomial-time solutions.

Comment: For this question to make sense you must say how the groups are given as input.

Comment: i didn't understand what you've said, the groups I've thought are general groups, so the input are just two groups.

Comment: @GuilhermGondin: To have similarity with the graph isom problem your groups should be finite. Even in that case the phrase "given two groups" is very imprecise.